# How can I store empty value in GAE LinkProperty?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

By default LinkProperty() is empty. But let us say I submit a form that stores site link in the DB field with the property LinkProperty(). This works fine so far.

Next, I want to delete that link stored in the DB by resubmitting the form with empty site link. At this time, I get database error as follows:
"BadValueError: link must not be empty."

Can anyone please help with this? Code below.

```
###Database
class MyDatabase(db.Model):
    site = db.LinkProperty()

###Trying to store form data in the database

mydb_obj = MyDatabase.get_or_insert('abc') 
#above line works fine

mydb_obj.site = self.request.get('form_site') #works fine. 
#Above form_site is read from form submission. It can be 'www.google.com' or it can be
#empty as in ''

mydb_obj.put() #I GET ERROR WHEN form_site = ''. 
#"BadValueError: link must not be empty"
```

Comment: Not sure why there was a negative vote on this question. If someone can explain that will help so that I can correct the question and get an answer :-). Thanks.

Comment: You should post your code so we could better understand the context of the error. Also, if your application is new, consider using NDB instead of DB: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

Comment: Thanks! Added code. NDB is not an option at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works

```
mydb_obj.site = self.request.get('form_site')
if not mydb_obj.site:
  mydb_obj.site = None
mydb_obj.put()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to replicate this error. It could be possible that the when the link input is empty, the value requested is `None`. Perhaps this might work:

```
mydb_obj.site = self.request.get('form_site')
if mydb_obj.site is None:
    mydb_obj.site = '' # value is empty string instead of None.
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above but I get the same error. "BadValueError: link must not be empty." It appears empty value cannot be stored in LinkProperty() at all?